# How to get status of a checkbox in Jquery DataTable?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to understand how do I get the status of a checkbox in JQuery Datatable to be sent back to controller.
Here is a small sample code from a DataTable definition - it has two columns - name and status which is the checkbox that I am interested in:

```
columns: [
{ "width": "1%", "className":"dt-body-left", 'data': "name" },
{
    "width": "5%",
    'data':   "status",
    "render": function (data, type, row){
        if (type === 'display'){
            return '<input type="checkbox" class="editor-active" name="chkbx1" value="col0">';            
        }
        return data;               
    },
    className: "dt-body-left"
},
]
```

User can add new items to table and when work is done submit it. Submit is done by looping through all entries of a datatable and creating model array to be sent back to controller. I can read all the properties, but checkbox status is always 1 independently of its status.

```
$("#sendToController").on('click', function()
{
var dataArray = [];
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var data = table.rows().data();
data.each(function (value, index) {
             dataArray.push(
             {
                 Name: value.name,
                 Status: value.status,
             });
});

$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: "/Home/StartCheckTest",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataArray),
    success: function (event){}
})
```

});

This should be a very simple operation - user clicks in the checkbox and script just reads the value, yet I have spent 2 days on it. How do I get the checkbox value in the loop? Does there need to be some additional logic under check/uncheck events? Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Comment: usually you can get the status with `.prop('checked')`, which returns true or false

Comment: @toffler Hi, this works with individual checkboxes, but how to update this syntax so it would work inside the loop?

Comment: Hi, you can try by using selector. i.e : Add this line `var selector = $("#example > tbody")` outside your `each` loop and for status you can use `Status :selector.find("tr:eq(" + index + ") [name=chkbx1]").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0` .